# Unable to connect with sqlalchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to set up and test a relational database in the simplest manner possible. I am able to connect using pyodbc via

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=USER-LT\SQLEXPRESS'
    'DATABASE=DBTEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

but when I do the same thing in sqlalchemy,

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=USER-LT\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=DBTEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
engine.connect()
```

I get the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush;
consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Invalid object name 'test'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); 
[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I have also tried,

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@USER-LT/SQLEXPRESS/RAMF_SM?trusted_connection'
    '=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server', echo=True)
```

without success.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Your first `create_engine` example works fine for me with SQLAlchemy 1.3.2 under Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Really? You get no error message after engine.connect()?

Comment: Really. [This](https://pastebin.com/sQJTiBYw) works fine for me.

Comment: No idea what was different. Copy pasted your code and it worked.